# BigQuery API Job AllowLargeResults

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently passing `allowLargeResults:True` to the BigQuery API via a Job, and I am getting the following error:

> Reason:invalidQuery. Message:Unclosed string literal at: 1:779

The strange thing is that if I set it to `False`, it works fine.

**My full job:**

```
{u'status': {u'state': u'RUNNING'}, u'kind': u'bigquery#job', 
u'statistics': {u'creationTime': u'1442029780703', u'startTime': 
u'1442029780902'}, u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'api-project-617799710969', 
u'jobId': u'job_1UBxC6nXSBRRerkGNUNr6_DdyPU'}, 
u'etag': u'"m-xx"', u'user_email': u'xx@google.com', u'configuration': 
{u'query': {u'query': u'SELECT * FROM table ', u'writeDisposition': 
u'WRITE_TRUNCATE', u'allowLargeResults': True, u'destinationTable': 
{u'projectId': u'api-project-617799710969', u'tableId': u'table', 
u'datasetId': u'dataset'}}}, u'id': u'api-project-
617799710969:job_1UBxC6nXSBRRerkGNUNr6_DdyPU', u'selfLink': 
u'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/api-project-617799710969/jobs/job_1UBxC6nXSBRRerkGNUNr6_DdyPU'}
```

Comment: Try passing string "true".

Comment: I have tried that, however it is automatically changing it to True. I am using the official python api wrapper: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html

Comment: I mean passing string enclosed "true", as the generation JSON is invalid without string quote wrappers.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but the python wrapper internally transforms it to a boolean.

Comment: Hey barsch! Do you mind including the code you use to generate said job? If the change from "true" to True is made by the wrapper, maybe it's something worth reporting on the BQ issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list)?

Comment: Actually, I found the problem. I had a regex in my query and did not brak one character inside it. Strangely though, the query worked fine with allowLargeResults=False, but as soon as I changed it to True, the query failed. Nonetheless, the wrapper changes "True" to True.